# Solidity - can I get information about a specific transaction within a contract?

Tags: solidity, transactions

What I'm hoping to do is get information about a specific transaction in my solidity contract.

For example, let's say I have transaction 0x0xxx, I would like to be able to pass that into a function, and get information about the transaction, specifically the sender address and the tokens transferred.

I know that I can get the blockHash:

```
blockhash(number)
```

But can I go a step further and get information about transactions within that block.

I've also read that you can only get info about the last 256 blocks, and that is not an issue at all.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this without setting up an oracle.

I just couldn't find much documentation about this specific use case.

Thanks very much;